# How to access the variable of loop inside ajax success function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback

I have a code that makes simultaneous ajax requests. However I want to access the value of i(loop variable) inside the success function of ajax request. Here is my code:

```
arr=['one','two','three']
value="wow"
for(var i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
    $.ajax({
      url: '/some_url',
      method:'POST',
      data:{
        'something':arr[i],
        'onething':value
      },
      async: true,
      success: function(data) {
        if(data.error==true){
          //Here, i need the value of i for some reason
        }
        else{

        }
      },
      error:function(error){
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  }
```

I am asking if I am doing this entirely wrong.Or Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: for what reason do you need the value of i ?

Comment: @niceman In nth child(i), I need to modify html elements

Answer (score 2):

in your solution, javascript flow won't preserve the value of `i`. you need to create `closure` to make the javascript preserve the value of `i`. try this one,

```
arr=['one','two','three']
value="wow"
for(var i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
    (function(i){ // self invocation functino
      $.ajax({
      url: '/some_url',
      method:'POST',
      data:{
        'something':arr[i],
        'onething':value
      },
      async: true,
      success: function(data) {
        if(data.error==true){
          //`i` should correctly here now
        }
        else{

        }
      },
      error:function(error){
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
    })(i); // we are suppling the value of `i` here
  }
```

notice the body of for loop.

Comment: Now I am getting value of i 2 in all success function. What I want is value of i to be changed according to loop

Comment: your statement "What I want is value of i to be changed according to loop" confused me. above solution should print the correct value of `i` according to the `for` loop i.e. as `0,1,2`. did you enclose the `for` loop body in self-invocation function correctly, as shown in above solution?

Comment: Yes, I did exactly like you did, and now there are no any ajax requests being made.The self invocation function is not running.

Comment: I"m not sure what the OP was missing here but this works.  Thanks!